# FormsAppCompatActivity and custom ActionBar/ToolBar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-actionbar

I am working on a **Xamarin.Forms** app, where I was using a **FormsApplicationActivity** as my main activity and was able to customize the **ActionBar** with a custom view inside it (I put a **Spinner** in it, for some page)

But since there was a few UI / look and feel issues I upgraded to **FormsAppCompatActivity**.
Since I did that I just CAN'T get my spinner in the toolbar / actionbar! No matter what I try!

This was basically the previous code, wroking with **FormsApplicationActivity**

```
        var activity = (Activity)this.Context;
        var bar = activityActionBar;
        var dlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        bar.CustomView = new Android.Widget.Button(activity) {
            Text = "Click",
            LayoutParameters = dlp,
        };
        bar.DisplayOptions = ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom;
```

What should I write to support **FormsAppCompatActivity** please?

Answer (score 1):

When using FormsAppCompatActivity the NavigationRenderer on android creates a new toolbar internally. It is a private field so far I can see and cannot be accessed.

here is the code : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/d1a8477233b28e6a20c6f5d4a75128ec2a05e6dc/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/NavigationPageRenderer.cs

See image for the specific code part. I am also trying now to get access to view. So just a note the action bar you are trying to edit is the wrong one. That one is created on activity startup.

[image]

UPDATE: maybe found a solution look here : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69923/access-to-the-formsappcompatactivity-bar

Comment: Thanks for that!
I might have a look soon.. (problem is still there.. only saw your answer today! :) )